# Navigation controller set to null, using UITabBarController

Tags: xamarin.ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an IOS app built with Xamarin, Visual Studio on the Mac.

In my SceneDelegate I create a UITabBarController with about 9 tabs. Each tab is a UINavigationController that has the View Controller I'm displaying as its root. (This is done so that some of my views can push subviews onto the view stack.

My problem is that when I click on a tab, and then back to the first (left-most) tab. And then push a view controller with it's NavigationController, the pushed view has a null Navigation controller. Why didn't the push set the NavigationController of the pushed view successfully?

Thanks,
Gerry

Comment: we can't debug code we can't see.   [mcve]

Comment: Hi , you should share some code about question , then I will check where problem is .If you want each tab is a `UINavigationController` , you can set `UINavigationController` as root controller for application. Then set `UITabBarController` as the SubController of `UINavigationController` . Having a try with this way to check whether can push view . By the way , not forgetting to share code in question .

Comment: I have not been able to create a simple example program.That makes me thing that the problem is hidden in the complexity of my app, it could be something that I'm doing wrong. I'll investigate it from that end for now. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, if the NavController is the root for the TabBarController then the TabBarController disappears when views are pushed. That is not the desired behavior and makes the TabBarController mostly redundant.

Comment: @Gerry Okey , it depends on your logic in project . If more info , remember to share here later .